# Lumen $request->all() returns empty array

Tags: http, curl, swagger, swagger-ui, lumen

I'm trying to make a POST request from Swagger UI to my server (Lumen), but everytime I just get an empty array instead.

Swagger UI request:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{   \ 
"stocks":[   \ 
   {   \ 
      "contract-number":0, \ 
      "metal-id":0, \ 
      "amount":0, \ 
      "unit":"string" \ 
   } \ 
] \ 
}' 'http://backend.mywebsite.de/v1/stocks'
```

My controller:

```
...
public function stocksPost(Request $request)
{
        dd($request->all());
}
...
```

And the output:

```
/var/www/vhosts/localhost/htdocs/vendor/illuminate/support/Debug/Dumper.php:23:
array(0) { }
```

But if I send the same request with Postman, everything works just fine:

```
    /var/www/vhosts/localhost/htdocs/vendor/illuminate/support/Debug/Dumper.php:23:
array(1) {
  'stocks' =>
  string(68) "[{"contract-number": 0,"metal-id": 0,"amount": 0,"unit": "string"} ]"
}
```

I don't get my problem, could somebody clarify it to me, please?

Comment: Open your postman request and ask it to generate Code for the request. Select cURL as language and validate it against your Swagger request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the Swagger request was that it sent my data in double quotes, due to that it can't be verified as JSON and could be only obtained from php://input as a string. I solved the problem just using my own curl requests, where I either put JSON data into single quotes or attach it as a external file.

```
curl -X POST -d @foo/bar/contractsPayload.json http://backend.mywebsite.de/v1/stocks -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept:application/json'
```